# Moving UIButton is not clickable?

Tags: ios, objective-c

We have this animation for some bubble effect on a button , but it prevent him from being clickable. if we disable this animation he works.

Can we fix it to let it work with the animation ?

```
 CGRect initi=[[initialPositions objectAtIndex:b.tag] CGRectValue];
        int r1=arc4random()%4;
        int r2=arc4random()%4;
        initi.origin.x+=r1;
        initi.origin.y+=r2;


        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.8 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^
         {
            b.frame=initi;

         }
          completion:^(BOOL completed){    }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, the button is not actually disabled or unclickable during the animation. When the animation starts the button's touch area is immediately moved to the position where the button will be when the animation ends. This makes it feel like the button were unclickable during the animation.

From touch logic's point of view, the button is just moved from A to B and animation between A and B is just eye candy. This explains why touching doesn't work between the points.

The only working solution to this is to roll your own animation routine. If you want to take this route, this post called [The Holy Grail of iOS Animation Intervals?](http://www.bigspaceship.com/ios-animation-intervals/) by Ben Bojko should point you to the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

As Markus says in his answer (voted) the button actually moves to it's end position at the beginning of the animation, and will accept clicks there as soon as the animation starts. The animation actually takes place in view hierarchy's "presentation layer".

You can use Markus' suggestion of doing your own animation, but that is processor-intensive and not as smooth as layer-based animation (which is how UIView animation works under the covers.)

If you want to use UIView animation and have your button respond to clicks while the animation is in-flight then you need to make the superview that bounds the entire animation clickable, and implement hit testing on the button's presentation layer to figure out if the tap hits the button or not. (the superview takes the tap, then checks it's coordinates to see if it is inside the buttons' presentation layer using the `hitTest:` method.)

I have a project on github called [**iOS CAAnimationGroup demo**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/iOS-CAAnimation-group-demo) (link) that shows how to do this, both for CAAnimation based animation and UIView-based animation.

Comment: thanks, ok i got it . so i would like to detect touches and check intersections , how do you get touches on screen in iOS8 ?

Comment: Make the superview that contains the button clickable, and either attach a tap gesture recognizer to it, or make it a custom subclass of UIView and implement touchesBegan/touchesMoved/touchesEnded. (A gesture recognizer is simpler and cleaner - that's what I would suggest).